# (Uber RIBs) Passing data across RIBs

Tags: android, ios

Given that

1. there are two RIBs modules, `A` and `B`
2. `B` is attached to `A` and `A` presents `B`
3. `B` reads data from `A` via `dependency/stream` and displays the data

^this above scenario is pretty straightforward.

My question is, what if I want to add a dummy/pure UI screen `C` in between `A` and `B`.

so the new flow is like...

`A` presents `C`(only contains a button which navigates to `B`)
Obviously, `C` does not contain any business related logic. But how does `B` get data from `A`, do I need to create a RIB module for `C`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dependency injection.

Uber also has a DI library you can use in conjunction with RIBs

https://github.com/uber/needle